# How to prove that every simple left $R$-module is isomorphic to a minimal left ideal of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

We know that:

$T$ is a simple left $R$-module $\Longleftrightarrow T\cong R/M$, where $M$ is a maximal left ideal of $R$.

> So please tell me how to prove that every simple left $R$-module is isomorphic to a minimal left ideal of $R$?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't prove it, because it's generally false for an arbitrary ring: $\mathbb{Z}$ has no minimal ideal.

Comment: So u can prove that if $R$ is semisimple ring?

Comment: Rings for which all simple right ideals embed in $R_R$ are called **right Kasch rings**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rings don't have minimal ideals, in general. For instance, $\mathbb{Z}$ has none, because $n^2\mathbb{Z}\subset n\mathbb{Z}$ properly, when $n>1$.

If $R$ is a semisimple ring, then the assertion is true: any submodule of $R$ splits; if $M$ is a maximal left ideal of $R$, then $R=M\oplus T$ for some left ideal $T$; then
$$
R/M=(M\oplus T)/M\cong T
$$
and so $T$ is a minimal left ideal which is isomorphic to $R/M$.